# How can I dynamically add an item to REMenu?

Tags: ios, drop-down-menu, remenu

I am trying to add a new item dynamically onto my menu made with [REMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/REMenu).

From the library, I could only find initWithItems method to load up the menu.

Answer (score 0):

`REMenu` is not much extensible, so why don't you just present new menu with your new item and hide old one, or, extend the class for your needs? Cheers!